# How to get percentile in java

Tags: java, hashmap, percentile

I have a list where I want to get percentile.

```
HashMap<Integer,String> test=new HashMap<Integer,String>();  
test.put(100,"Amit");  
test.put(101,"Vijay");  
test.put(102,"Rahul"); 
test.put(103,"Amit");  
test.put(104,"Vijay");  
test.put(105,"Rahul");
```

Using following formula for percentile, how can I iterate and use properly?
i  want to get percentile of each keys in hash map

```
Number of scores blow X*100/N
```

Comment: not clear what you want ? explain in brief

Comment: i  want to get percentile of each keys in hash map

Answer (score 0):

So i haven worked that much with HashMaps, but looking at the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) it should be something like

```
Hashmap<Integer><String> h;
int sum = 0;
for(int i: h.keySet()) {
  sum += i;
}
double percentile = sum/h.size()
```

Comment: i dont want key i awnt ot get percentile of ech key

Comment: If i got that correct, then ure just looking for double perc = 1/h.size(); EDIT: nvm, ill Change my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this (assuming by percentile you mean relative to the highest score what everyone scored, if you want distribution then you may want to use different computation but this should give you an idea)

```
    int maxScore = 0;
    for ( Integer score : test.keySet()) {
         if (score > maxScore) {
             maxScore = score;
         }
    }
    for ( Integer score : test.keySet()) {

         System.out.print(String.format("%s's percentile %5.2f\n", test.get(score), 
                 ((double)score/(double)maxScore)*100));
    }
```

Using the data you have you should get something as below

```
Rahul's percentile 97.14
Amit's percentile 98.10
Amit's percentile 95.24
Vijay's percentile 96.19
Vijay's percentile 99.05
Rahul's percentile 100.00
```

Comment: if i need to get  based on value?